# Select store inside store from the appState

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, store

I have a store like this

```
    {
      rootStore: {
        firstStore: {
          el: false,
          sec: false,
          th: []
        }
      }
    }
```

how can i get the first store in one go (using one select statement), now I use

```
() => (state: Observable<any>) => state.select('rootStore').select('firstStore');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use `map`:

```
() => (state: Observable<any>) => state.map(store => store.rootStore.firstStore);
```

As an alternative, since select is basically an alias for `pluck` this works as well:

```
() => (state: Observable<any>) => state.select('rootStore', 'firstStore');
```

Comment: cool, the second one works too, thanks, that what I was looking for